# android pop all activities and put selected activity on top of starting activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have couple of activities , let say A, B, C, D, E , Where A is the starting activity . On all the activities I have a navigation drawer with tabs to start these activities. The type of behavior I m planning is that no matter where the user is he will be able to swipe the navigation drawer and switch to any activity of choice. In this case every time a new activity is started (Other than activity A) all the activity from stack should be removed and the stack should only have (Activity A and the new started activity)

How can I remove all activity from the stack and put the chosen activity on top of Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clear the stack, just set FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to the intent you are starting: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) is the link for the official documentation.

Comment: but which ever activity i open , upon clicking back on it the root activity should appear.

Comment: then try also overrideing `onBackPressed()`